# KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent Before API Level 21 equivalent?

Tags: android, security, android-4.4-kitkat

I would like to use the

KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent

To allow the OS to verify the identity before allowing the user of my app to access secure information. This works very well for requirements of the application. Since this allows the OS to handle the verification over pin, pattern, fingerprint or what ever the user already has setup.

Unfortunately this only available in API level 21 and later, what was the previous design pattern for Android for verify the user?

We have supported API level 16 previously, I fear that requiring 21 or later would restrict our install base considerably.

Comment: You need to implement DeviceAdmin API for your application. By using that you can lock the device and when user unlocks you will get callback `ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED`. This is not very similar to what you are doing but it can help you to identify your user. Read more at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html

Comment: Yeah adding DeviceAdmin would probably not be acceptable to most users, it was decided to just lock this feature to API 21 and above. Not great but only limits roughly %30 of our users.